# All C# scripts create errors despite not having any errors present and perfectly building and running on its own

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

As seen here
[image]

The default project created by typing `dotnet new console` creates all of these errors.
I'm currently running CODE-OSS version 1.47.1-1, Manjaro Linux, and the C# extension is version 1.22.1.

```
dotnet --info
```

outputs

```
    paul@ManjaroKDELaptop ~/D/ProgramProject [1]> dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.103
 Commit:    6f74c4a1dd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     manjaro
 OS Version:  
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.3
  Commit:  ed88943d24

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.103 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Omnisharp logs are as follows

```
    Starting OmniSharp server at 7/31/2020, 10:42:21 PM
    Target: /home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject

OmniSharp server started with Mono 6.8.0.
    Path: /home/paul/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1/.omnisharp/1.35.3/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 8193

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on manjaro 0.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Mono 16.4 - "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin"
            2: StandAlone 16.4 - "/home/paul/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1/.omnisharp/1.35.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Mono 16.4 - "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            CscToolPath = /home/paul/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1/.omnisharp/1.35.3/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject/ProgramProject.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject/ProgramProject.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject' on host 8071.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file '/home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject/ProgramProject.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project '/home/paul/Documents/ProgramProject/ProgramProject.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: ProgramProject
```

This is what the ProgramProject.AssemblyInfo.cs file looks like.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("ProgramProject")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Debug")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("1.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("ProgramProject")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("ProgramProject")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]

// Generated by the MSBuild WriteCodeFragment class.
```

And this also is riddled with errors.

[image]

Finally, the .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs file is also riddled with errors.

```
// <autogenerated />
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1", FrameworkDisplayName = "")]
```

[image]

As seen here

[image]

The actual program runs flawlessly.

In this scenario, how would I go around fixing these issues?
Any help with this issue would be great. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure this would 100% fix the issue, but it's likely caused by Omnisharp picking mono MSBuild instance over the one that ships with c# extension (info is near the top of the log). I think you can poke with this https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options to point it to the inbuilt one, or even uninstall the other one if you don't really need it..

Comment: @MisaJovanovic thanks. I'll try this solution.

Comment: @MisaJovanovic BTW, do you know what the thing shipped with the C# extension is called?